# Как делаются многостраничные приложения на Angular?

Tags: angular2

В общем, изучаю Angular и задался вопросом:
Ну скажем, если захочется мне как-то разграничить логику между 2-мя страницами, то смогу ли я это сделать? Если да, то каким образом это делается?

Искал примеров и не нашел.
Сейчас, как я понимаю после прочтения мануалов, запускается страница Index и в ней по селекторам замещаются элементы на компоненты.

Или такое делать на Angular нельзя и все рендерится на странице index?

Comment: что такое "страница"?

Comment: Вы про [роутинг](https://angular.io/guide/router)?